# 'Plan of development' or 'Development plan'?

Tags: word-usage, word-order

I was once preparing a presentation for english-speaking executives on a factory. I had a slide titled 'Plan of development'. During the review one of the fancy pants corrected me saying that this is incorrect form and I should change it to 'Development plan'.
Same happened several more times, each time they asked to change `X of Y` to `Y X`.

> Part of machinery — Machinery part
>
> Day of May — May day
>
> etc.

The question is: Is there a rule that states which form is correct?
And if both forms are acceptable, what's the difference between them?

Comment: Be careful about May day / Mayday. The rest depends on the context surrounding the phrases.

Comment: 'Plan ~for~ development' is more common in the US (vs 'of') if we're talking about real estate types of development, but you could definitely also say "development plan".  "key for access"  vs "access key" could both be used with "access key" probably preferred in some cases but perhaps not if there were different sorts of keys like front door keys, backdoor keys etc. I'd say, it really depends on your specific circumstance which method would be more common or in some cases have the right nuances.

Comment: If you blew up a machine, the debris would be better called "parts of machinery" as "machinery parts" would imply (to me at least) intact specific parts and components. (I'm just expanding on my "it depends" comment)

Answer (score 1):

**Development plan** sounds much easier on the ear of a native speaker of English. Plan of development is technically fine, but sounds more cumbersome.  Also I would capitalise to support the idea that your Development Plan is a stand-alone entity that you would give importance to.

Comment: But why 'Department of Defense', 'Part of speech', 'Day of week' then?

Comment: Terms like **grammar rules** and **rules of grammar** would be fairly interchangeable and roughly equivalent IMO.  But when you get to cases like DoD and Part of speech, then factors like historical frequency of use have greater influence on choice.  The alternate forms of these would be reasonably intelligible to most readers.  However, **weekday** has a very different meaning to **day of week** in most common usages.  So, you must take each case on its individual merits.  Getting back to your OP final question, unfortunately no iron-clad rules when it comes to these aspects of English.

Comment: "Terms like grammar rules and rules of grammar would be fairly interchangeable and roughly equivalent" 
That's what I wanted to hear! My dignity was hurt when they said that the form I used is grammatically incorrect : )

Answer (score 0):

A noun word can modify another noun word, noun + noun. eg a meeting room, paper money, Christmas party. you may not say the room of meeting.